# Online resources for meanings and examples of radicals in simplified Chinese

Tags: simplified-characters

I've done a brief search through CSE, but found nothing too helpful. Are there any online resources that explain the meaning of the radicals followed by some examples in simplified Chinese?

Comment: If you use Pleco (the Chinese Dictionary app) there is an addon dictionary and a flashcard list for radicals and explanations here: http://www.plecoforums.com/threads/radical-dictionary-flashcards-ios-android-tested.1149/ but I haven't tried it myself so dunno if it's suitable for you.

Comment: I compiled a list of the 100 most common radicals here: http://www.hackingchinese.com/kickstart-your-character-learning-with-the-100-most-common-radicals/ It contains simplified, traditional, variant forms, meaning, pronunciation, example characters and colloquial names.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [mdbg.net's radical section](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=radicals). The first charachter on each individual radical's page is always the character the radical comes from followed by the radical itself (if they're different), followed by anywhere from a couple to several hundred charachters with that radical in simplified and traditional. Clicking on a charachter on any of the radical page takes you to the dictionary which shows the character in both simplified and traditional.

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Zdic](http://www.zdic.net/), just type and search. Content rich but entirely simplified Chinese.